# Code First migrations updating the wrong Db on localdb

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using code first migrations to create and update the database for my asp mvc site.

I have a DbContext, which is in another project in the solution.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }
}
```

When i enable-migrations and add-migration **[name]**. It seems to create its own db called

```
[foo-projectname].Domain.Concrete.EFDbContext
```

Instead of the attaching to the database i created, called **[foo-projectname]**.
In the webconfig for the site the connection string is referencing by catalog "**[foo-projectname]**".

If i change the webconfig to the other database , then i get results back from items i have added into the that database. However i want to use the database that i created.

The reason i do not want to stick with this auto created one is because i am not sure on the migration to SqlServer and do not want to get stuck further down the line. I am also getting the error

> The model backing the 'EFDbContext' context has changed since...

even when i have not changed anything.

Comment: when you run the migration, what was your active project on NPM console? what was your active startup project? what is the project name that has DbContext class?

Comment: @YuliamChandra The project name which has the migrations is [foo-projectname].Domain which is the active project in NPM, this one also has the DbContext Class . The active startup project is the other project [foo-projectname].Web

Comment: just to rule out the startup project, could you try it again with parameter `-StartUpProjectName [foo-projectname].Domain`

Comment: Nope that did the same thing. [foo-projectname].Domain is not the startup project though. This localdb is confusing me

Comment: OH FLIP .. I think i understand what you mean. So i set the startup project as [foo-projectname].Web . I was under the impression that because it built to the .Web project that by default it was the startup project. Thanks for bouncing off ideas!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

X is the project name that contains derived `DbContext` class.

- Make sure the `Default project` on `Package Manager Console` is X
- Make sure the active start up project on the solution is X

Another workaround is, provide following parameters when running the migration syntax.

```
-ProjectName X -StartUpProjectName X
```

Some Parameters Description:

```
-ProjectName <String>
    Specifies the project that contains the migration configuration type to be
    used. If omitted, the default project selected in package manager console
    is used.

-StartUpProjectName <String>
    Specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings. If
    omitted, the specified project's configuration file is used.

-ConfigurationTypeName <String>
    Specifies the migrations configuration to use. If omitted, migrations will
    attempt to locate a single migrations configuration type in the target
    project.

-ConnectionStringName <String>
    Specifies the name of a connection string to use from the application's
    configuration file.

-ConnectionString <String>
    Specifies the the connection string to use. If omitted, the context's
    default connection will be used.
```

Comment: Can you maybe expand on why this is happening? Is there a difference between localdb and connecting to SqlServer, and could it also be that because I have authentication in the [foo-projectname].Web which connects to EFDbContext?

Comment: @gerdi, no, the StartUpProjectName is used to look for the connection string, if ommitted it will use the solution's start up project (find the configuration and find related connection string) or the connection string in the configuration