# Switching from EF Automatic Migration to Code-First-Migration

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am currently attempting to switch from Entity Framework Automatic Migrations to Code-First Migrations. For a little backstory, this solution is split into four seperate projects: Data, Models, Services, and Web. The connection string information is located in the Web project, and the context is located in the data project.

Now, I have ran "Enable-Migrations", and that appears to have worked correctly.

From there, I delete the existing migrationHistory table in the database.

Running

```
Add-Migration -projectName Data"
```

will generate an appropriate migration.

The Problem is when I attempt to run Update-Database, it results in a generic error:

```
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified)
```

I can connect to the database using the credentials supplied in the web.config, and the database connections have worked appropriately for the past several months, so I do not believe it is a connectivity problem unless Code-First migrations requires a different port than Automatic Migration.

I assumed that it was just not seeing the connection string supplied in the web.config, however running

```
Update-Database -projectName data -startupprojectname web
```

results in the same error

My question:

How do I get around the generic network-related error, given the above information? Is this problem a visiblity problem, in which the data project code-first migrations cannot see the connection string in the web project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code first migrations - what connection string will it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532704/code-first-migrations-what-connection-string-will-it-use)

Specifying the connectionStringName in the Update-Database / Add-Migration worked properly.

```
Update-Database -projectName Data -connectionStringName MyConnectionString
```